# Алгоритм Бабушкина

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть реализация алгоритма в MATLAB:

```
format longG % вывод: 15 знаков после запятой
clear res;
res=0;

for num=1:10
    a=fix(rand(3,1)*256); % вектор из шести байт
    st=[0 1 2];
    a_10=256.^st*a/10^8; % число-отображение вектора

    m=1;
    for n=5:1:10^8 % увеличиваем n
       while (a_10>double(m/n))
           m=m+1;
       end
       if (abs(a_10-m/n)<=0.5/10^9) % совпало!!1
           break;
       end
       m=m-1;
       if (abs(a_10-m/n)<=0.5/10^9) % совпало!!1
           break;
       end
    end

    % выведем наш результат:
    l=length(res(:, 1))+1;
    res(l,1)=a(1);
    res(l,2)=a(2);
    res(l,3)=a(3);
    res(l,4)=a_10;
    res(l,5)=m;
    res(l,6)=n;
    res(l,7)=m/n;
end
```

Помогите пожалуйста перевести в php.

Comment: Или это алгоритм архивации, который сможет сжимать фильмы размером 2ГБ до 2-3 кБ

Comment: user262975 - Бабушкин? Интрига...

Comment: До 2-3 кб не сожмёт, но для моих целей отлично сойдёт)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.compression.php ;)

Comment: Это не подойдёт, мне нужно именно то, что в примере. На входе будут числа и на выходе должно быть тоже число.